# Issue with images when converting HTML to PDF using itextPDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, file-conversion

I'm converting html to pdf using itextPDF, everything works as expected but for one of the GIF image after conversion to pdf only the skeleton  of the image appears. This is a static GIF image not animated just an image with transparent background and image in center. when I run the code through other GIF images with transparent background works as expected. I'm using the below code to convert HTML to PDF. I have attached a sample image of the issue.[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY4sY.jpg)

```
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(inMemoryStream);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(test, temp, converterProperties);
    temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
    merger.merge(temp, 1, temp.getNumberOfPages());
    temp.close();
    pdf.close();
    inMemoryStream.close();
```

Comment: no able to share the image because of Privacy issue, but when using other html to pdf conversion tools like openpdf this issue is not solved. I'm wondering how other tools are handling such images when converting html to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem if you understand how PDF handles transparency.

[image]

It does not matter if an Image is TIFF PNG or GIF with transparency they are all stored in a similar fashion as 2 images. One is the opaque DeviceRGB the other is the Alpha channel as a black "SoftMask" we can see one image in left column, and 2 images mentioned in right column, and the 2 images (RGB overlaid with SoftMask)  in the central PDF view.

The issue here is bad image generation as the SoftMask has not been drawn well [image]

It should look like this (masked) for imposition in HTML or PDF and the foot shadow dealt with accordingly.
[image]

One of the interesting Points about PDF is we are told you cannot import a "Transparent" JPG, but perhaps you can now see **how this PDF has a JPEG with transparency** so is smaller (21,674 bytes) than a GIF (41,679 bytes) or PNG variant. and not look any worse in resolution colours or gamut.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining that it does make sense now. But is there a way  itextPdf has a work around for this as some of the libraries does for such images?

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfMerger;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

    

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class HtmlToPdfConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace "test" with your HTML content as a String
        String htmlContent = "<html><body><p>Your HTML content here</p></body></html>";

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream inMemoryStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(inMemoryStream);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
            ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();

            // Add your custom properties if needed
            // converterProperties.set...

            // Convert HTML to PDF
            InputStream htmlInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes());
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlInputStream, pdf, converterProperties);

            // Close the PDF and perform further operations
            pdf.close();

            // Now you can work with the generated PDF in 'inMemoryStream'
            // ...

            inMemoryStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about issues with a specific bitmap image in the html. Your html fragment does not include any image at all. So is your proposal in your answer not to use images?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).